# Replace string at specific start end positions javascript

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, substring

I want to replace a string at specific start and end indices,

```js
str = `kunal 11 12 13 kunal 11 12`;

matches = [{
    Start: 0,
    End: 10
  },
  {
    Start: 15,
    End: 26
  }
];

str1 = '';
for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  str1 = str.slice(0, matches[i].Start) +
         `<span>${str.substring(matches[i].Start, matches[i].End)}</span>` +
          str.slice(matches[i].End);
}

console.log(str1);
```

I have written one piece of code, that is only replacing last match, is there some predefined method which I am missing?

Comment: By `str1 = ...` you are overriding previous values.

Comment: @undefined is there some prebuilt method in javascript to replace in the range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `str1 = str.slice...<other manipulations of str>` means that the resulting `str1` depends only on what `str` is, and not on what `str1` might have been previously. So, if you reassign `str1` on the first iteration, and then reassign it on the second iteration, the second version will not contain any of the changes made in the first version.

To fix it, you might iterate over `matches` *from the largest `Start` to the smallest `Start`*, rather than the other way around, while `.slice`ing the *modified* string, which will ensure that the new inserted text doesn't break your `matches`' `Start` and `End` properties:

```js
const input = `kunal 11 12 13 kunal 11 12`;
const matches = [{
    Start: 0,
    End: 10
  },
  {
    Start: 15,
    End: 26
  }
];
let str = input;
for (let i = matches.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  str = str.slice(0, matches[i].Start) + `<span>${str.substring(matches[i].Start, matches[i].End)}</span>` + str.slice(matches[i].End);
}

console.log(str);
```

Comment: `To fix it, you might iterate over matches from the largest Start to the smallest Start, rather than the other way around, while .sliceing the modified string, which will ensure that the new inserted text doesn't break your matches' Start and End properties:` can you explain a bit more on this?

Comment: See how the new `for` loop starts at `matches.length - 1` and iterates downward, rather than the other way around? Without that, the initial change to `str` would mess up all the remaining indicies in `matches`, eg https://jsfiddle.net/eprsd39v/ you'd get `<span>kunal 11 <span>1</span>2 1</span>3 kunal 11 12` because the new `"Start: 15"` after the first change does not refer to the same point in `str` that `"Start: 15"` did originally. So, go the other way around, changing the end of the string first.

Comment: this is a very clever trick, I debugged line by line your solution and it works perfectly for me, what is this technique called?

Comment: No idea if there's a name for it, it was just a solution I thought of when I saw what the problem was.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) with a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get the result. The reduceRight is initialized with `str`, and on each iteration (from the last match to the first), it takes the previous state of the string, updates it with the match, and returns the result.

```js
const str = `kunal 11 12 13 kunal 11 12`;
const matches = [{ Start: 0, End: 10 }, { Start: 15, End: 26 }];

const result = matches.reduceRight((r, { Start: s, End: e }) =>
  `${r.substring(0, s)}<span>${r.substring(s, e)}</span>${r.substring(e)}`, str);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very clever solution indeed, this solution does not mutate the original string also!